# Атака на asterisk. Как заставить fail2ban банить брутфорсеров?

Tags: asterisk

```
[2019-07-18 08:11:36] NOTICE[7739]: chan_sip.c:28627 handle_request_register: Registration from '"7020" <sip:7020@45.66.8.225>' failed for '195.154.220.71:5230' - Wrong password
[2019-07-18 08:11:36] NOTICE[7739]: chan_sip.c:28627 handle_request_register: Registration from '"7100" <sip:7100@45.66.8.225>' failed for '195.154.220.71:5230' - Wrong password
[2019-07-18 08:11:36] NOTICE[7739]: chan_sip.c:28627 handle_request_register: Registration from '"7101" <sip:7101@45.66.8.225>' failed for '195.154.220.71:5230' - Wrong password
[2019-07-18 08:11:37] NOTICE[7739]: chan_sip.c:28627 handle_request_register: Registration from '"7102" <sip:7102@45.66.8.225>' failed for '195.154.220.71:5230' - Wrong password
[2019-07-18 08:11:37] NOTICE[7739]: chan_sip.c:28627 handle_request_register: Registration from '"7103" <sip:7103@45.66.8.225>' failed for '195.154.220.71:5230' - Wrong password
```

брутфорсят астер, в сисадинстве не особо силен, помогите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался. fail2ban стоит, но не банит.

fail2ban regex 
`^(%(__prefix_line)s|\[\]\s*)%(log_prefix)s Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>(:\d+)?' - (Wrong password|Username/auth name mismatch|No matching peer found|Not a local domain|Device does not match ACL|Peer is not supposed to register|ACL error \(permit/deny\)|Not a local domain)$`

какими путями заставить fail2ban банить брутфорсеров?

Comment: Asterisk какой версии?

Answer (score 1):

Если Asterisk 11+ версии, попробуйте так:

В файле /etc/asterisk/logger.conf выставить в секции

```
[logfiles]
security => security
```

Далее применить настройки

```
asterisk -rx 'logger reload'
```

Создать файл /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/asterisk.conf с содержимым ниже и при необходимости поправить значения на свое усмотрение

```
[asterisk]
enabled  = true
port     = 5060,5061
action   = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-tcp, port="%(port)s", protocol="tcp", chain="%(chain)s", actname=%(banaction)s-tcp]
           %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-udp, port="%(port)s", protocol="udp", chain="%(chain)s", actname=%(banaction)s-udp]
           %(mta)s[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s"]
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/security
maxretry = 3
findtime = 600
bantime  = 2592000
```

Перезапустить fail2ban

```
service fail2ban restart
```